# How can I convert a string in a file into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a .txt file and it has some numbers like

0,3,4, ... 9

................

1,2,5, ... 6

This is a sudoku design, I want to take this into an array

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner (new File ("sudoku1.txt")); //here I specified the target of the file like C:\\...
 for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
       String n = in.next();
     grid [i][j] = Integer.parseInt(n);
   }
 }
System.out.println(grid);
```

when I try to see the array, it give an error because of the " , " in the text file, if I delete commas and put spaces instead of commas, it works but even it shows me only 1 row and it does not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (new File ("sudoku1.txt"));
for(int i=0; i<9 && in.hasNextLine(); i++){
    String []nums = in.nextLine().split(",");
    for(int j=0; j<nums.length; j++){
        String n = nums[j].trim();
        grid [i][j] = Integer.parseInt(n);
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
```

Comment: it gives an error like "duplicate local variable n"

Comment: This time I got the result but it is like
[[I@5cad8086, [I@6e0be858, [I@61bbe9ba, [I@610455d6, [I@511d50c0, [I@60e53b93, [I@5e2de80c, [I@1d44bcfa, [I@266474c2]

Comment: Thank you so much, such an amazing job!

Comment: Arvind, could you please look my last question? It is also about this but much more complicated

Comment: :( Is there any way to ask you that question? Could you write me on mail? squirrelalone@gmail.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8cSPs9Wrtf/
Well, I put it in here, I would appreciate it if you could check it out

Answer (score 2):

Scanner can use other delimiters. The default one matches the whitespaces.

Here is an example.

```
String myDelimiterGroup = "[,\\r\\n]"; // a pattern definition
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(yourFile).useDelimiter(myDelimiterGroup);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't think to use delimiter, I am kind of noob.